# Can I use non-linear PCA (CATPCA?) on my multivariate dataset that contains nominal AND ordinal data?

Tags: pca, multivariate-analysis, nonlinear

In my multivariate dataset I have over 100 objects/cases that have been coded on 20 different variables. Several variables are ordinal and several variables are nominal. Is it possible to use non-linear principal components analysis as a dimension reduction technique on this dataset? I am not certain how to approach optimal scaling with the two types of variables simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, you can and may use. CATPCA (i.e. iterative PCA with optimal scaling) can take any categorical or discrete variables. A variable is quantified into interval-level variable either (1) linearly, (2) monotonically, (3) nonmonotonically, or (4) split into a set of dummy variables. The choice is yours. For an ordinal variable you normally should use (2), and for nominal variable, (3) or (4). Note that if you use (4) for all your variables, CATPCA becomes identical to Multiple Correspondence analysis (MCA=HOMALS). Please search `CATPCA` on this site for more.